# Dropdown on focus not positioning itself above following div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a drop down `div` on focus of a `<input type='text'>` box as follows

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/7ffdF/

I need the dropdown box to appear above the `container-box` div that follows the search box. Currently it's pushing the div downwards. Is there a way I can make this text box behave like a `select` tag without having to use the `select` tag.

My CSS for the dropdown div is

`display:none;z-index:200;`

On focus of the  search box, the div appears using:

```
$('#text-box').focus(function(){
    $('.dropdown').show();
});
```

I also need the div to disappear on removing focus.

Summarizing, I've got two questions:

1. Regarding the positioning of the drop box
2. Toggling of the dropdown on and off focus of the search box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;` for the dropdown. And also use Jquery event `blur` on text field to hide it

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ffdF/19/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#text-box').focus(function(){
        $('.dropdown').show();
    });

    $('#text-box').blur(function(){
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.container-box {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.dropdown{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:200;
}

.dropdown ul {
    padding :0;
    background : #ddffaa;
}
```

Styling the drop-down is in your hands :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` to stop the dropdown from being in document flow, so it doesn't interrupt other elements.

You can also use `.blur()` for what to do when there's no focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ffdF/12/

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 400px;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#text-box').blur(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the div position to absolute....

```
div.dropdown{
    width:170px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

I set up a good example for you on this [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/7ffdF/18/)